# Not working alert changing text content with next button jquery

Tags: jquery

to click a menu changing content area. if click the "menu2" or "menu3", not working "next" button.

```
// Menu click 
$(".nav ul li a").click(function () {
    var x= $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('.tbClass').removeClass('pTabActive');
    $('#c'+x).addClass('pTabActive');
    $('.nav ul li').removeClass('mActive');
    $(this).parent().addClass('mActive');
    //location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); /* URL Parametre Location */                          
});

// Navigation Click
$(".btnNext").click(function () {
    var x= $('.nav ul li').attr('class');
    var $item=$('.nav ul li.'+x);
    var $index=$('.nav ul li').index($item); // selected menu index
    alert($index);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ertbihal/kBuCe/13/

How can I make it work?

Comment: You should post your code here, not only a link to js fiddle. If it will became broken, you question will be useless for future users.

Comment: @FAngel Updated the code here... :P

Comment: First thing is you should not add numeric values to classes or IDs...

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you should not add numeric values to classes or IDs... You are not referencing the class correctly.

The below code always displays `mActive`:

```
    var x= $('.nav ul li').attr('class');
```

#### Working Code:

```
// Navigation Click
$(".btnNext").click(function () {
    if ($(".mActive").next().length)
    {
        a = $(".mActive");
        a.removeClass("mActive");
        a.next().addClass("mActive");
        b = $(".pTabActive");
        b.removeClass("pTabActive");
        b.next().addClass("pTabActive");
    }
});

$(".btnPrevious").click(function () {
    if ($(".mActive").prev().length)
    {
        a = $(".mActive");
        a.removeClass("mActive");
        a.prev().addClass("mActive");
        b = $(".pTabActive");
        b.removeClass("pTabActive");
        b.pre().addClass("pTabActive");
    }
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kBuCe/17/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var x= $('.mActive').attr('id');
var $index=$('.nav ul li').index($("#"+x));
alert($index);
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/kBuCe/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// Menu click 
var menuItems = $(".nav ul li a").click(function () {
    var x = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('.tbClass').removeClass('pTabActive');
    $('#c' + x).addClass('pTabActive');
    $('.nav ul li').removeClass('mActive');
    $(this).parent().addClass('mActive');
    //location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); /* URL Parametre Location */                          
});

// Navigation Click
$(".btnNext").click(function () {
    var $item = $('.nav ul li.mActive');
    var $index = $('.nav ul li').index($item); // selected menu index
    if ($index < menuItems.length-1){
        menuItems[$index+1].click();
    }
});

$(".btnPrevious").click(function () {
    var $item = $('.nav ul li.mActive');
    var $index = $('.nav ul li').index($item); // selected menu index
    if ($index > 0){
        menuItems[$index-1].click();
    }
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kBuCe/15/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is perfect for you :

```
// Menu click 
$(".nav ul li a").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().addClass('mActive').siblings().removeAttr('class');    
  $('#c'+$(this).parent().attr('id')).addClass('pTabActive').siblings().removeClass('pTabActive');  
});

// Navigation Click
$(".btnNext").click(function () {        
  var _index=$('.nav ul li.mActive').index() + 1;
  if(_index <= $('.nav ul li').length)
    $('.nav ul li').eq(_index).find('a').click();   
});

$(".btnPrevious").click(function () {
   var _index=$('.nav ul li.mActive').index() - 1;
   if(_index >= 0)
    $('.nav ul li').eq(_index).find('a').click();   

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ducwidget/kBuCe/18/